# Jenkins raising mantisbt issues

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, mantis

I have set up mantis with the [mantis plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mantis+Plugin) to raise issues if a build fails. Now, the build have been failing for a few days (don't ask!) but a new issue is opened every day.

How can I set the [mantis plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mantis+Plugin) so that if there already is an issue opened, it append a note to the current one instead of creating a new one?

[Jenkins issue link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35916), since there is no activity here.